# Convert flat map with dotted keys into hierarchical json

Tags: json, groovy

I have a hashmap (unsorted) with dotted key value pairs like

```
person.adress.street=Fakestreet
person.adress.nr=123
person.name=Mike
person.adress.city=Springfield
```

And I would like to convert it into a valid json structure like:

```
{
   "person" : {
     "name" : "Mike",
     "adress" : {
       "street" : "Fakestreet",
       "nr" : 123,
       "city" : "Springfield"
      }
   }
}
```

I there a library or some standard groovy functionallity out there or do I need to handcraft such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `groovy.util.ConfigSlurper` [as per @cfrick's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606438/groovy-map-dot-keys-to-nested-map)

or shorten your hand-made solution like that:

```
Closure nester

nester = { Map rslt, String key, val ->
  String[] keys = key.split( /\./, 2 )
  if( !rslt.containsKey( keys[ 0 ] ) ) rslt[ keys[ 0 ] ] = [:]
  if( 2 == keys.length ) nester rslt[ keys[ 0 ] ], keys[ 1 ], val
  else rslt[ key ] = val
  rslt
}

def d = [ 'person.name':'Mike', 'person.adress.street':'Fakestreet', 'person.adress.nr':123, 'person.adress.city':'Springfield', 'aaa':'bbb' ]

def tree = d.inject [:], nester.trampoline()

assert '{"person":{"name":"Mike","adress":{"street":"Fakestreet","nr":123,"city":"Springfield"}},"aaa":"bbb"}' == JsonOutput.toJson( tree )
```

Comment: while the config slurper is really cool, it sadly does not handle arrays the way I need it. So I have updated my own answer. Just for the interested people which also need array handling

Answer (score 1):

Ok, actually it was not so time consumig to hand craft it as I thought. Not sure if there are any flaws but for the momentent this seem to work.

```
def makeJson(properties) {
    println properties
    def sorted = properties.sort { a, b ->
        def x = a.key.split("\\.").length <=> b.key.split("\\.").length
        def y = a.key <=> b.key
        return x != 0 ? x : y
    }

    def tree = [:]
    sorted.each {
        def parts = it.key.split("\\.")
        def node = tree

        for (def i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
          def next = parts[i+1]

          if (next.isInteger()) {
            node = node.get(parts[i], [])
            node[next.toInteger()] = [:]
          } else {
            node = parts[i].isInteger() ? node[parts[i].toInteger()] : node.get(parts[i], [:])
          }         
        }

        def last = parts[parts.length - 1]
        node[last.isInteger() ? last.toInteger() : last] = it.value
    }

    return JsonOutput.toJson(tree)
}
```